# Create an database entity in one thread and try to retrieve the same entity in another thread gives different result

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa

I am trying to create a scenario where I create an entity in main thread and then use another thread to query the same entity that was just created. However, if I execute the query to fetch the entity outside of the thread, it returns value. However, if I query it inside the thread, I get `null`. I have attached the source code with comments and tried to make it simple. I would appreciate if anyone can help me point out the issue. I am using `JPA` and `Spring framework`. For database, I am using `postgresql`. Thank you. Here is the sample program:

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Employee generatedEmployee = employeeService.createEmployee(passEmployeeInfo()); // CREATE TEST EMPLOYEE.. passEmployeeInfo() just sets name, phone etc.
        System.out.println(generatedEmployee.getReferenceId()); //Output is: 20

        generatedEmployee.setReferenceId(30L); //update the referenceId here...
        long refId = generatedEmployee.getReferenceId();

        Employee employeeFromDB = employeeQuery.getEmployeeByReferenceId(refId); //Use refId to get Employee from table
        System.out.println(employeeFromDB);  //Output is:  Employee [id=2, refId=30, ...]

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Employee employee = employeeQuery.getEmployeeByReferenceId(refId);
                System.out.println("The employee inside run method is: " + employee); //Output is NULL here.. This is what I am trying to understand.
            }
        });
        thread.start();
}
```

Comment: To answer this I would need to see a bit more code. Please also post your employeeService.createEmployee function, the Employee.setReferenceId method and the employeeQuery.getEmployeeByReferenceId function.

Comment: Why not DEBUG it? look at the log of the JPA provider you use. Look at timing of the commit in one thread compared to the read in the other thread. Dont use an EntityManager across threads. aka debugging ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points to Note:

- Spring will apply a transaction to your test method and will by default roll the transaction back when the method completes.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#rollback

- Spring transactions do not propagate to new threads.

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-and-threads-transactions

So therefore the method completes and rolls back the transaction before the lookup in the new Thread executes.

If you add the `@Commit` annotation to your test method the record should be found.